# Find peaks not larger than a value MATLAB

Tags: matlab, find

There is a command in  MATLAB2017 as follow:  findpeaks()

In the documentation has been discussed about the minimum prominence of the peak in the command below:

```
findpeaks(PeakSig,x,'MinPeakProminence',4,'Annotate','extents')
```

There is nothing about "the maximum prominence of each peak" in the documentation.

In order to count the peaks not larger than 2*std I tried to employ threshold option as below:

```
[pks,locs,widths,proms]=findpeaks(dTrendoxi);
stdProms=std(proms);
FsOxi=80;
figure(3), findpeaks(dTrendoxi,'Threshold',2*stdProms)
```

but it seems I could not use threshold option to control the maximum peak prominence.

Do you have any solution how I can use threshold command to count the peaks with prominence not larger than 2* std?

Best

Comment: what about just doing x(x>2*std)=NaN ?

Comment: Yes, you are right..  this could be a solution but I wanted to know whether would be possible to employ option "threshold" for this purpose or not